# How to delete an element in an array depending on another array modification in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays:

```
x=np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1])
y=np.array([y0,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9,y10,y11,y12])
```

Where the elements y_i correspond only to the 0-elements in the array x.

I want to modify one random 0-element in x and to make it 1. At this time, I have to delete the corresponding element in y (because y contains only element related to 0 in the array x).

[EDIT:] for example, I have

```
x=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0]
 y=np.array([21,32,45,54,87,90,88,60])
```

such that to x[0] corresponds y[0]=21, x[1]—> y[1]=32, x[2]—>y[2]=45, x[3]—> y[3]=54, x[4]—>y[4]=87, x[7]—>y[5]=90, x[8]—>y[6]=88, x[10]—>y[7]=60. If I change x[2], x[7] and x[10] from 0 to 1, I want to cancel the corresponding elements in y, i.e. 45, 90 and 60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
x_0 = np.where(x==0)[0]

rand_ind = np.random.randint(1,len(x_0))

x[x_0[rand_ind]] = 1;

y = np.delete(y, rand_ind)
```

`x_0` is an array of elements in `x` initially equal to 0. `rand_ind` is a random index chosen from `x_0` length range. To change 0 to 1 the program uses `x_0[rand_ind]` while to delete the corresponding element in y it simply uses `rand_ind`.

---

This is a modified solution for the updated question,

```
import numpy as np
import random

x_0 = np.where(x==0)[0]

rand_ind = np.array(random.sample(list(x_0), 3))

x[rand_ind] = 1

y = np.delete(y, [np.where(x_0==i)[0] for i in rand_ind])
```

In this solution rand_ind is a direct choice of indices of the x array and not the trimmed x_0 array. It chooses the indices stored in x_0 to avoid choosing indexes where the value in x is 1. The indexes i.e. elements of x_0 are the indexes of x while the indexes of x_0 correspond to indexes/positions in y.

Program uses `random.sample` as a straightforward way to pick N elements at random without repetition (here 3). It then turns the elements at `rand_ind` in x to 1 and deletes the corresponding elements in y. The last step is done by using a generator and finding the indices of x_0 elements with each rand_ind value.

Comment: Glad to help :) The best way is probably to simply generate `rand_ind` as an array, `randint` has that option.

Comment: Thanks! But I have another question about it. If I change the value in the 2nd and 7th position in array x, the program you wrote doesn't delete the correspondent element in y... I tried to put your code in python with this specific example but it doesn't work properly...

Comment: I mean, I have x=[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0] and y=[21,45,32,98,12,5,3], for instance. I want the 2nd and 6th element from 0 to 1. So your program does it. Since the elements in y are related only to null x elements, there won’t be correspondence in indices between x and y, right? In this way, I want to delete the elements 32 and 5 because they correspond to x-elements I changed. It seems that your program doesn’t delete the right elements from y, no? Thanks for your helpful discussion!

Comment: It was right as I wrote before! Try to explain better: x=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]) and y=np.array([21,45,32,98,12,5,3]). So, to x[0] corresponds 21=y[0], x[1]->45=y[1], x[2]->32=y[2], x[3]->98=y[3], x[4]->12=y[4], x[6]->5=y[5], x[7]->3=y[6]. The indices of y-elements is different at a certain point from those of x-elements. This happens because in x there's an element =1 (that is x[5], that isn't related to any elements in y). If I change x[2] and x[6], how can I remove the corresponding elements in y, i.e. y[2]=32 and y[5]=5? I know that it's an insanity, but I need to do it in this way...

Comment: If you don’t have any solution Maybe it’s better to post it in another thread to have more visibility... thanks for this discussion :)

Comment: Edited the original post. Problems raise when the 1s are more than 1

Comment: ok I get it now. My program btw. does essentially the same thing. It draws indexes from a shortened array which simplifies things greatly.

Comment: I deleted most of my comments not to flood the post, updated the answer. It  does, I think, exactly what you want it. I left the old solution too.

Comment: Very well!!! Thanks a bunch! I was in trouble with for loop and if conditions but I was writing bad something and I was going crazy. Thanks thanks thanks

Comment: :)) you're welcome! Still, the first solution works and does the same thing. It just operates on indices of x_0 instead.